# Average waiting time objective in job shop problem with OR-Tools

Tags: python, or-tools

I implemented a flexible [job shop problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop) with Google OR-Tools (following [this example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py)) in which jobs are submitted over time and the objective is to minimize the average waiting time of the jobs (or equivalently, the sum of the waiting times), instead of the [makespan](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/fa84bc05e72641dddfbb98164d81b8bc9bef6ea5/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py#L154).
Following the code of the example, I defined mine as:

```
model.Minimize(sum(job_starts))
```

where `job_starts` (defined similarly to `job_ends` in the example) contains the list of the variables corresponding to the jobs' starting times.
Notice that technically I am minimizing the sum of the starting times, but since the sum of the arrival times is constant, it should be equivalent to minimizing the sum of the waiting times.
I also included a constraint for each "start" variable that ensures that it's greater than the corresponding arrival time.
While the above approach works (it produces the desired result), it seems significantly slower (3 orders of magnitude) slower than the corresponding problem with a makespan objective. Is this normal (the average waiting time objective is inherently "harder") or am I defining it in a sub-optimal way (maybe due to the use of `sum` due to the absence of a `addSumEquality` method in OR-Tools?

Comment: could you share your code?